# How to access Azure private node using web3js in Azure websites?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, ethereum, go-ethereum

I have setup node in Azure VM (OS Windows) successfully. Below are the commands

```
geth  --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir testprivareDir --port "30303" --nodiscover --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --networkid XXXX
```

In my code hosted in Azure websites

```
new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://publicIP:8545"));  **-- not working**

new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://dnsname:8545"));  **-- not working**
```

**Note**

- I can access it in Remix web3Provider using localhost:8545 **inside the VM with the node**, but I can't access outside the VM using the public IP (publicIP:8545) or the DNSName:8545
- I have port 30303, 8545, 22,8000, 8080 open in network security group of the VM
- The node is currently mining successfully as well
- `rpccorsdomain "*", --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0, try also --rpcaddr StaticIP`

I am thinking if I can access it in Remix outside the VM with node, it should probably work as well in Azure websites.

Comment: Should `web3Porvider` be `web3Provider`? Please edit this if so.

Answer (score 0):

Will answer my own question so others can see it also.

In the Azure Network Security Group - make sure port 22 is the first priority (priority 100).

- Before - set up is 8545 priority 100, 22 priority 101 - **did not work**
- After  - set up is 22 priority 100, 8545 priority 101 - **it worked :)**

I am not really sure at moment why this ordering affects it.